# how to get correct response from bing this api

Tags: bing-api

when i submit  any question this Api response its question title and answer

for example question: Difference between PHP and CODEIGNITER 
this api provide me related this question answer and title

when i submit file name (as book like somthing) and its  type as pdf ms word powerpoint and excel 
this api response me all realated  file title file url and description

this code response me correct image

```
 $key=$this->input->post('search');
     if($key){ 
     $accountKey = 'WEGUEed3yF9CI6ZzVblKD0HoMRG3/rOELkCda9VYsuk=';
     $ServiceRootURL =  'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';  
     $WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Query=';

     $request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $key . '\'');

     $process = curl_init($request);
     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $accountKey . ":" . $accountKey);
     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     $response = curl_exec($process);

     $jsonobj = json_decode($response);


     foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $value)
     {                        
    echo('<li style=" margin-left;170px;" class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->MediaUrl . '">'); 
    echo('<img style=" margin-left;170px;" src="' . $value->Thumbnail->MediaUrl. '"></li>'); 
    }

     echo("</ul>");
}
```

how to get required question and its answer and files title and its url from this code
any one can help me how it is possible

Comment: This question is vague and difficult to understand. The code you posted works fine, as it lists a bunch of images. Not sure how that relates to Word, Excel, and PowerPoint. Also, note that you posted your secret API key that others can steal and use. Not a good idea ;)